# NGINX generic laravel redicts

Tags: apache, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am facing this issue- I have a folder on my `NGINX` webserver that holds all my Laravel webs. I previously had an `Apache2` server that forwarded example.com requests to that folder and in every single folder there was a .htaccess that just forwarded request to `/public` folder where `index.php` is (its default behaviour of Laravel projects).

Unfortunately, after switch to NGINX this does not work anymore. I`ve tried several configurations that would simply take a project name from url (example.com/**someProject**), and act like its root directory is **/var/www/laravel/someProject/public**) - I want to perform this is generic way. There maybe dozens of projects so hardcoding project names for each configuration is something I want to avoid.

I`ve came up with something like

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name webs.example.com;
    root /var/www/laravel;

    index index.php;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/webs.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/webs.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel;
    }

    location @laravel {
        rewrite ^/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /$1/public/index.php?$query_string last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$1/public/index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/([^/]+)/public/(.*)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/public/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ ^/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Certificate works like charm, unfortunately nothing else work as intended. When trying to access some project that is present (and has proper permissions setup- when I just make a static server that leads directly to /projectName/public, everything work like charm), I a getting `503 Forbidden` (which I get when I try to access root folder of that laravel web- only **/public** folder should be accessible- due to this fact I believe I am not being redirected to /public properly). There were some attempts where I could write `someProject/public` and I saw a webpage, but the desired goal- to have `webs.example.com/someProject1` `webs.example.com/someProject2` is something I can not master.

Is there anyone who knows how to do this set up properly?